# Docker throws error while running npm install for node application

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops

```
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN mkdir /project-api
WORKDIR /project-api
RUN apk add --update-cache python

ENV PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/
COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf ~/.npm
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN rm -f package-lock.json
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
```

I was trying to create a node container for my project, but it throws some error while npm install (bcrypt package). I tried installing  python in image file.But still it shows error. I'm attaching error screen[image]

Comment: That PNG file isn't very easy to read.  Can you delete it and replace it with the actual text of the error you're getting?  If the error is in your `npm install` step, including the contents of your `package.json` file (again, as text, inline in the question and not behind a link) is probably essential to help debug things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bcrypt` npm package depends on non-javascript code. This means it needs to be built for the specific architecture it's being run on. The initial "WARNING: Tried to download" indicates a pre-built artifact wasn't available, so it's falling back to building from source.

The specific error I see is `Error: not found: make`, which indicates [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) isn't installed on the image you're building on (`node:12-alpine`). Either install it in a prior step in your dockerfile, or switch to a base image that has it pre-installed (`node:12` might).

The `bcrypt` package have more specific instructions at https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#alpine-linux-based-images.

> You need the following packages:
>
> - build-base
> - python
>
> ```
> apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python
> ```